# How can I prevent my newly created conda environment from containing pip packages inherited from `pip` from the conda default environment?

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

To save a conda environment and re-create it, I use:

```
# Save the environment
conda env export > my_conda_env.yml

# Re-create the environment
conda env create --file my_conda_env.yml

# Reactivate the environment
conda activate pytorch
```

However, when I do so, in the new environment the `pip freeze` lists some python packages that were not specified in the `my_conda_env.yml` but instead comes from the `pip` from the conda default environment. How can I prevent my newly created conda environment from containing pip packages inherited from `pip` from the conda default environment?

I notice that `my_conda_env.yml` contains `prefix: /home/franck/anaconda3/envs/pytorch` on the last line. What's the point of it?

---

```
> echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/code-base/runtime/app:/home/code-base/runtime/app/python:/home/code-base/runtime/app/python/dev:/app/python:/app/plugins:/app/plugins/jupyterlab-zip
> echo $PATH
/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/opt/conda/bin:/app/python/bin:/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Why does the conda default environment have those packages in the first place, if you don't want them to appear in every new environment?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel set up by the sysadmin

Comment: The new env should be completely isolated from the **base** when activated under recommended configuration settings (e.g., `conda init` section in `.bashrc`). Is the **base** env being added to PATH manually, or is PYTHONPATH being used (it shouldn't be)?

Comment: @merv thanks, I've added PATH and PYTHONPATH in the question. Are they used by conda virtual environments? If so, it seems you found what was the issue :-)

Comment: I think `pip` uses `sys.path`, which in turn uses `PYTHONPATH` to discover packages. Generally, `PYTHONPATH` should be empty to ensure environment isolation.